# Ошибка при установке VirtualTreeview

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Устанавливаю компонент VirtualTreeview на delphi XE2 вылетает ошибка:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] VirtualTreesR.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'VirtualTreesR' must be recompiled
```

и ещё одна

```
[DCC Fatal Error] VirtualTreesD.dpk(36): E2202 Required package 'VirtualTreesR' not found
```

хотя вначале я компилил файл VirtualTreesR и этот файл лежит в той же дириктории

Answer (score 1):

Принудительно прописать в окружении путь к BPL